# Errors when starting a new android application project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new at this Android stuff so please forgive me. I downloaded the Android SDK Bundle and when I opened up Eclipse and started a new Android Application project but when I hit finish a bunch of errors poppped up in Eclipse console and it won't finish or open up the project. Anybody have any reason why this is happening?

**UPDATE**
I finally got it working on eclipse but now it won't let me run my project. An error box saying "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches" also I have tried going into AVD to create a new device and the ok button is grey-ed out and I can't create anything. Any reason why both of these things are occurring?

Comment: You've given no information in this question so no one will be able to resolve this for you. My advice is to copy the error and Google it with a search term like "eclipse new Android application NullPointerException(101)" almost all basic setup issues can be resolved through Googling

Comment: `it won't let me run my project` Probably, your manifest's **minSdkVersion** is **too high** for the emulators you have, if any. `also I have tried going into AVD to create a new device and the ok button is grey-ed out` There are some errors in your AVD parameters. Google on how to create a proper AVD in Eclipse.